# Is it possible to extract the first value from a list and pause the iteration until the user say yes?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, loops

I have an Excel file consisting of some values.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | USA | No |
| left | center | Brazil | No |
| AEF | BCD | Germany | No |
| One | Two | India | No |

I wanted to extract the columns "C"& "D" and wanted to check if the column D is "No" or other value.

```
for i, j in zip(D, C):
    if i == "No":
        print(j)
```

I will be getting an output of the countries from C after this. But I would like to have the first value of the list ("USA") to be extracted first and use it as an input in another line, such that the remaining code works. [ie; I have to use the value from the column C to download some data with the country name as input]. After the download I would like to change the list or column D to "Yes" and do the same for the next iteration. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can add an input statement to pause it. That way, when the keyboard is pressed, you can continue processing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to start looping through a list and continue printing when a 'y' input is received..

```
# create the list
new_list = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]

# start looping through list
for i in range(len(new_list)):
    print(new_list[i]) #print the values
    #ask the user if they want to continue
    user_input = input("Continue? Y/N: ").lower() #convert to lower() to ignore case
    if user_input != "y":
        break # exit if the user enters anything other than 'y'
```

I trust you can use this logic to achieve what you need.

Comment: Your logic is correct. but the issue is that, this logic only works with the values in the new list. I wanted to loop through the main list [checking the corresponding columns C&D and take each value from C if the column D is "No"]
N.B: After the iteration, i want only the first value from the list as an input to another function --> run that function --> if it succeeds, --> change the value in column D to "Yes" ---> rerun the loop (search for the next "No")

Answer (score 0):

You could consider making those 2 list as a dataframe and can manipulate the iteration and the values inside the dataframe while iterating the same.

```
  for i, row in cd.iterrows():
        if row.center== "No":
            print(row.left)
            cd.at[i, 'center'] = "Yes"

            print(row.left)
```

so the output will be like;

| left | center |
| --- | --- |
| USA | Yes |
| Germany | Yes |
| Brazil | Yes |